# How to have centered title and an image on just on right in responsive header

Tags: html, css

First, I'm so sorry because I know that it's possible, but I really suck at CSS.

This is what I'd like to do:
[image]

I've managed to do it but it's really messy... The main issue is that my header isn't responsive at all and I'd to know what is the best way to do it (I know that usually flexbox is a good practice when it comes to build something responsive but my issue is that if I create 2 columns thanks to Flexbox I won't be able to align them just next to each other).

This is my current code (I know it's uggly):

```css
header {
  background-color: #c16200;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  z-index: 1;
  max-height: 8vh;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.08em;
  position: relative;
}

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 35%;
  height: 2.5em;
}

.line {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 17em;
  height: 2px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}

.header-sentence {
  margin-top: 0.2em;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<header id="myHeader" class="sticky">
      <div class="header-title">
        <h1>
          Title
        </h1>
        <img
          src="https://cdn.glitch.com/33ba966f-5c93-4fa3-969c-a216a9d7629c%2F167931478_735371457343939_8305934260393763828_n.png?v=1617205161517"
          class="logo"
          alt="logo plane"
        />
        <div class="line"></div>
        <p class="header-sentence">
          subtitle
        </p>
      </div>
</header>
```

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HTML with CSS it is sometimes a good idea to do some nesting of elements.

I used an wrapper element (`.header-title-composition`) to layout title, line, and subtitle vertically . This is all wrapped alongside the paper plane inside `.header-title`, which is responsible for the horizontal layout

```css
header {
  background-color: #c16200;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  z-index: 1;
  /* This destroys everything inside this demonstration */
  /* Basing a height on the actual viewport's height is somewhat dangerous */
  /* max-height: 8vh; */
}

.header-title {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; 
}
.header-title :first-child {
  margin-left: auto;
}
.header-title :last-child {
  margin-right: auto;
}
h1 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.08em;
  position: relative;
}

.logo {
/*  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 35%;*/
  height: 2.5em;
}

.line {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 17em;
  height: 2px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}

.header-sentence {
  margin-top: 0.2em;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<header id="myHeader" class="sticky">
  <div class="header-title">
    <div class="header-title-composition">
      <h1>
        Title
      </h1>
      <div class="line"></div>
      <p class="header-sentence">
        subtitle
      </p>
    </div>
    <img src="https://cdn.glitch.com/33ba966f-5c93-4fa3-969c-a216a9d7629c%2F167931478_735371457343939_8305934260393763828_n.png?v=1617205161517" class="logo" alt="logo plane" />
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here somewhat of a starting point for you. First of all, I added `.header-brand` as wrapper for title, line, sentence and image. Used `display: flex` for alignment. The additional media query takes care of the alignment, when the screen size is below 480px (But try it out on your own, since there are probably still some issues with that)

```css
header {
  background-color: #c16200;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  z-index: 1;
  max-height: 80vh;
  display: flex;
}

.header-brand {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.08em;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
}

.logo {
  height: 2.5em;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.line {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 17em;
  height: 2px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}

.header-title {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.header-sentence {
  margin-top: 0.2em;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .line {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .logo {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<header id="myHeader" class="sticky">
  <div class="header-brand">
    <div class="header-title">
      <h1>
        Title
      </h1>
      <div class="line"></div>
      <p class="header-sentence">
        subtitle
      </p>
    </div>
    <img src="https://cdn.glitch.com/33ba966f-5c93-4fa3-969c-a216a9d7629c%2F167931478_735371457343939_8305934260393763828_n.png?v=1617205161517" class="logo" alt="logo plane" />
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Combine `flexbox` and a simple wrapper using `text-align: center`, the decorated line can be a pseudo-element.

```css
h1,
div,
p {
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #c16200;
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: sticky;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  z-index: 1;
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
}

.logo-wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

header img {
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

h1::after {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 1px;
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<header class="sticky">
  <div class="logo-wrapper">
    <h1>TITLE</h1>
    <p>the tag line</p>
  </div>
  <img src="https://cdn.glitch.com/33ba966f-5c93-4fa3-969c-a216a9d7629c%2F167931478_735371457343939_8305934260393763828_n.png?v=1617205161517" class="logo" alt="logo plane" />
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want the element which contains the title and subtitle centered, and the image aligned right to that, not both together centered. So here's a solution:

The `.title-container` is centered within the `header` using `display: flex` and other flex settings (see below) on the `header`. Avoiding *both*  the text container and the image to be centered together is done by applying `position: absolute` to the image, making it a child of `.title-container` and applying `position: relative` to `.title-container` to make it the position reference for the absolutely positioned image. That way the image isn't considered at all when centering the `.title-container`.

Take a look at the position parameters for the image: Vertically-centered alignement is achieved by `top: 50%` and `transform: translateY(-50%);`, the horizontal position is done with a *negative*  `right` value: -2.5rem, i.e. the width of the image (2rem) plus 0.5rem for the distance to the text container. Adjust all values as needed.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #c16200;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 1rem;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
}

.title-container {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}

.title-container .line {
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 2px 0 4px;
}

.title-container img {
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  position: absolute;
  right: -2.5rem;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.title-container h1 {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin: 0;
}

.title-container p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="title-container">
    <h1>TITLE</h1>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <p>SUBTITLE</p>
    <img src="https://cdn.glitch.com/33ba966f-5c93-4fa3-969c-a216a9d7629c%2F167931478_735371457343939_8305934260393763828_n.png?v=1617205161517" class="logo" alt="logo plane" />
  </div>
</header>
```